# How to enable an application to run at Ubuntu start up which is installed using Wine?

Tags: wine, startup, startup-applications

I installed some applications using Wine in my Ubuntu 14.04. I need some of that applications to run at system start up. One such application is NetWorx(an application to measure bandwidth usage). How can I do it ?

---

UPDATE :

I need to run the application in the User account too. Is that possible ? If yes, how ? If no, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its 100% possible. You just need to open **Startup Applications** and add a new startup program. The command will be something like `wine "/home/$user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/you/program.exe"`

Replace `$user` with your username.

For example if I wanted to run IE at startup it would be something like:
`wine "/home/dakota/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe"`

Make sure to keep the quotation marks in the command or it will not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, fill `wine yourprogram.exe` on commands field:
[image: Add startup program]

Comment: This didn't worked. Why ?